# Why does Query function result in empty cells when the Range is not empty?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

Query function in Google Sheets results in empty cells for certain columns whereas ends appropriately for some other columns that carry the same values as the former.

Googling, StackOverflow etc etc

query function of Range A2:A4 to another sheet results appropriately. Whereas B2:B4 having same values results in empty cells.

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? That way we should be able to find out what is causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most likely it's due to formatting (try to play a bit with **<kbd>`123`</kbd>** button).

also, you should be able to resolve it with `TO_TEXT` like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A2:A4), "select Col1", 0))
```

Comment: That '=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TO_TEXT(A2:A4), "select Col1", 0))' resolves my issue. Thanks a tonne.

Comment: I am extremely sorry. As I am new to this forum, I wasnt aware of the etiquette.

Comment: The query function works as per your answer. I would like to know why query of the aforementioned result gives me an empty output when I try this formula =QUERY('All payments'!A2:I,K1) where K1 is "select A,D WHERE I>=43601 AND I<=43601" and I is a date converted to number.

Comment: generally, it happens out of two reasons: data in cells are mixed (eg text strings with numeric values) or data in cells are referenced (eg outputted from another place/formula)

Comment: That doesn't help.  It results in an empty output as well.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mwn3yjN6hHd0FBL9CBuNzl4aNg5SAxo6yYMjTpRr1Pk


PLEASE CHECK SHEET 8, CELL H8

Comment: Hey I added " ' " to the numbers and the issue is resolved. Thanks for the support !

Comment: How do I add a sum function to the above formula and rearrange the some columns before the sum and some columns after the sum ? Link attached

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AX6iPfq5v1J-zVQCD6F5V21mwWVYQ8JQFmAHlAJnv3s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: you will need to nest multiple queries to pull this off

Comment: That worked.  Now I want to add a sum of a particular column in the query at the bottom that is offset to the left of the query result by +1row and - 3 columns.  Is it possible?